# Fetch mysql records where id is 0,10,20,30, etc

Tags: php, mysql

I have about 30 000 records in database, and I must create 10 cron jobs for these:

```
job 1 fetches records where column `id` is 0,10,20,30, etc.
job 2 fetches records where column `id` is 1,11,21,31, etc.
```

and so forth.

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [*modulo* operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod)

```
select * from your_table
where id % 10 = 1
```

to get `1,11,21,31,...` and so on. And

```
where id % 10 = 2
```

for `2,12,22,32,...`.